# Post Form Jquery Repeteable + Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins

I need your help.

I have a form with some fields generated with Jquery Repeteable. In other words, I have fields with a similar name.

Now, in Laravel I need it once sent to be able to manipulate this information to generate an array

This is the code

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-3" hidden>
        <input type="text" class="span6 form-control" name="id[{?}]" value="{?}" id="id_{?}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="span6 form-control" name="umed[{?}]" value="{umed}" id="umed{?}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="span2 form-control" name="cant[{?}]" value="{cant}" id="cant{?}">
        </div>
```

In the controller i need this

```
        $sub_items = array(
        "txtITEM"                   => $request->id[],
        "txtUMED"                   => $request->umed[],
        "txtCANT"                   => $request->cant[],
    );
```

I know that i need a foreach but i dont know how, please i need your help

Answer (score 0):

For input `name` attribute you need add square brackets after each name

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3" hidden>
    <input type="text" class="span6 form-control" name="id[]">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input type="text" class="span6 form-control" name="umed[]">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input type="text" class="span2 form-control" name="cant[]">
</div>
```

and you will receive `request` fields as array like so

```
$sub_items = array(
   "txtITEM" => $request->id,
   "txtUMED" => $request->umed,
   "txtCANT" => $request->cant,
);
```